# Manually setting up React Native libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, create-react-native-app

I'm currently writing an Android React Native app on VS Code using create-react-native-app and I'm trying to install some libraries to use, namely [react-native-html-to-pdf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tch4J_pP9o).

In the documentation, after the npm install, it asks me to run a link command which returns an error saying

> "Cannot read property 'pbxprojPath' of null".

Within my code, the import line `import { RNHTMLtoPDF } from 'react-native-html-to-pdf'` returns an error saying that the react-native-html-to-pdf module cannot be found.

How can I manually link this library with VS Code? I tried following the manual installation in the documentation but I believe that the Gradle files don't exist. If I try running the sample code provided to me, I get

> Cannot read property 'convert' of undefined

as an error, so I presume that the library is not correctly linked.

Comment: What is the exact npm command you did to install the library?

Comment: npm install react-native-html-to-pdf --save

Answer (score 0):

Applications created with `create-react-native-app` cannot link native modules unless you first [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md).

So, you must first run `npm run eject` to be able to use the `link` command. However, note that **ejecting is not reversable** and your project structure and general setup will change a bit with this operation, so make sure to first read the official [Ejecting](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) documentation before proceeding.